# Modular arithmetic AND Eucledian Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was studying how to find the modular inverse. Suppose the example is:
27*x is congruent to 1 (mod 392) .

Now we have to find x. In the process we write this Equation as:

x is congruent to 27^(-1) (mod 392).

Here is my confusion does in modular arithmetic we can simply take 27 from left hand side and move it to right hand side and write it as 1/(27) (mod 392) without considering the 1 (mod 392) present their already and inserting 1/27 in between of 1 and (mod 392). 
Because 27*x was congruent to 1(mod 392) but now we take x is congruent to 1/27 (mod 392).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @YuHao   I wouldn't say off-topic given the tags. This is the sort of thing you need to do if you want to implement anything like RSA. It is about math which is *directly* related to programming and has tags that are at the boundary between math and programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, try http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

This seems confused. If `27x = 1 (mod 392)` then *by definition* x is 27^-1 (mod 392). You don't solve this equation by "moving" things from the left hand side to the right hand side. You solve it by using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to write `27x + 392y = 1` in which case x is the inverse you seek since you can rearrange the equation as `392y = 1 - 27x` which shows that 27x differs from 1 by a multiple of 392 hence `27x = 1 (mod 392)`